# mustache template for key value pair

Tags: javascript, object, handlebars.js, mustache, templating-engine

so i have a json response i am getting from my api like this

```
{
  dailytask: [ { title: 'Chores', body: 'Wash the plates and vacuum the living room' } ],
  monday: [
    { title: 'madrid', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' },
    { title: 'opopo', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }
  ],
   teusday: [
    { title: 'exercises', body: 'jog 5k, lift and cardio' },
    { title: 'read', body: 'read up on kubernetes and Docker' }
  ],
   wednesday: [
    { title: 'read', body: 'continue learning VUE.js' },
    { title: 'shop', body: 'buy some clothes and a new mouse' }
  ],
}
```

how do i use mustache templating over these key, value pairs, i am trying to build a materialize card for each of the values like

```
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">**TITLE**</span>
          <p>**BODY**</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <span>**Any of the Properties(e.g dailyTask, monday, teusday, wednesday)**</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```